# Are questions about teaching writing on-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

I'm an experienced writer, and I am trying to teach some of what I know, in a working environment, to other members of my team.  Are questions related to *helping others write better* on-topic?  They're not questions about my own writing, and teaching inherently has a fair bit of push (not pull) so self-answered questions asked from their point of view aren't the best approach.

Answer (score 4):

I think they should be. My view is that anything that tilts the site towards the insights and experiences of working professionals the better -- and the more suitable for the SE format. Teaching writing is certainly one of the things that professional writers, particularly in industry, are frequently called on to do as part of their professional practice.